# Dimension of disjoint union of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

While it is clear that a disjoint union of two $d$-manifolds is a $d$-manifold, it is not clear to me if the disjoint union of a $d_1$-manifold and a  $d_2$-manifold is still a manifold and if yes  under some conditions then what is its dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most definitions of manifolds exclude the disjoint union of manifolds of different dimension from being a manifold.

Comment: In particular, to *really* answer your question you should tell us exacty what your definition of manidold is.

Comment: it is the standard definition: every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^d$

Comment: @palio: and what is $d$? (Is it allowed to vary or is it fixed?)

Comment: $d$  is the dimension of the manifold

Comment: (or, more precisely, where  the quantifier for $d$ put?...)

Comment: (Also: That is not the standard definition...)

Comment: well i said it roughly but wikipedia says the same thing: A topological space $X$ is called locally Euclidean if there is a non-negative integer $n$ such that every point in $X$ has a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space $E^n$ (or, equivalently, to some connected open subset of $E^n$).

A topological manifold is a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space.

Comment: Well, if you fix *that* definition, then no, a disjoint union of two manifolds of different dimension not a manifold (if $m\neq n$, then no neighborhood of a point of $E^n$ is homeomorphic to a neighborhood of $E^m$: this is an immediate consequence of the Theorem on Invariance of Domain)

Comment: are there different definitions of topological manifolds?

Comment: @palio and Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if), right?