# "A manifold with boundary has dimension at least 1" if it has a dimension and if it has nonempty boundary?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu.

As can be found in the following bullet points

- [Can a topological manifold be non-connected and each component with different dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273320/can-a-topological-manifold-be-non-connected-and-each-component-with-different-di/2273365#2273365)
- [Is $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ a manifold with boundary? My issue is the $2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146131/is-0-1-cup-2-a-manifold-with-boundary-my-issue-is-the-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Understanding topological and manifold boundaries on the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388254/understanding-topological-and-manifold-boundaries-on-the-real-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)

we have that

1. Tu's manifolds with or without boundaries do not necessarily have (uniform) dimensions.
2. Tu has considered manifolds to be manifolds with boundaries (with empty boundaries).

Question: For Definition 22.6 (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iUIj.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmETl.png)), Tu says that "A manifold with boundary has dimension at least 1". Should this instead be "A manifold with boundary has dimension at least 1 if it has a dimension and if it has nonempty boundary" or "An $n-$manifold with boundary with non-empty boundary has $n \ge 1$" (Notice that the prefix "$n-$" precisely gives the manifold with boundary a dimension)?

---

Embedding photos:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course, this entirely depends on how you defined things and, once you have fixed definitions, the answer will be trivial.

Comment: Also note that imgur is not accessible in every country. It is better to embed images directly into your post.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward You mean one might not access imgur directly but can be embedded imgur images?

Comment: Oh, they embed from imgur now? this is a shame.

Comment: If you are having so many issues with the definitions in a given textbook, it might be a good time to pick up another book. There are so many introductory smooth manifold texts to choose from. The world is your oyster.

Comment: Your comment means a lot to me but in the context of this other book I'm reading (I have more problems with From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220868/given-that-compact-subspaces-of-mathbb-rn-are-not-necessarily-manifolds-with) than with Tu's book, which I have already read most of). Thanks!

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Can you see the embedded pictures I added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Tu’s statement is fine:

A manifold, by definition, always has a dimension. Where are the charts going?

Usually when we say that a manifold “has boundary,” we mean that it has nonempty boundary.

---

After looking at some of Tu’s (*non-standard!*) definitions, I think you’re correct. An accurate statement might be

> If an $n$-dimensional manifold has nonempty boundary, then $n\ge 1$.

Comment: I'll add these to the post to make the post hopefully self-contained: 1. Tu's manifolds do not necessarily have dimension. 2. Tu has considered manifolds to be manifolds with boundaries (with empty boundaries).

Comment: Thanks Santana Afton! About non-standard, Tu said himself on stackexchange that these must be allowed: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3208774/636532). Your response? Haha

Comment: @SeleneAuckland When learning about these objects, the important part is understanding the **core** of what they are and how they interact with one another. These edge cases can be important — keep them in mind — but don’t dwell on them at the moment.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks!

Comment: Wait do you disagree with Tu in introducing dimensionless manifolds with or without boundary in an elementary differential geometry textbook?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland I think it’s a tricky issue. It depends on what you think the purpose of an introductory text is, what lessons an author wants a reader to learn from the text, etc. There’s a much larger conversation here about standard definitions vs. “proper” definitions, how mathematics “ought” to behave, teaching students, and so on. I personally disagree, but I’m not sure how much weight that has.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sensible definitions, an alternative solution is to change the statement to the following:

> A connected manifold with non-empty boundary has dimension at least 1

Edit: I rejected the suggested edit to change "manifold with non-empty boundary" to "manifold with boundary with non-empty boundary" because it does not add new information.  A manifold with non-empty boundary must be a manifold with boundary, or your definitions are nonsense.

Comment: Oh because connected manifolds with or without boundary, under Tu's dimension-less definitions, necessarily have dimensions?

Comment: Also, the rest of the sentence talks about "a discrete set of points". I don't think connected is what was intended. Why don't we just say "An $n-$manifold with boundary with non-empty boundary has $n \ge 1$" ?

Comment: I don't know what Tu's definition is, but for any sensible definition of manifold, a connected manifold will have a well defined dimension. I also cannot load imgur posts and cant see anything about discrete sets of points directly in your post.

Comment: The statement in Section 22: "A manifold with boundary has dimension at least 1 since a manifold of dimension 0, being a discrete set of points, necessarily has empty boundary." The definition of manifolds (without boundary) in Section 5: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273320/can-a-topological-manifold-be-non-connected-and-each-component-with-different-di/2273365#2273365)

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that a manifold could be dimensionless.  A manifold consists of connected components, each of which has a dimension. As for the statement in question, a more accurate phrasing would be

"If an n-manifold has nonempty boundary, then $n \ge 1$"

or

"A connected manifold with nonempty boundary has dimension at least 1"

as was pointed out above by various commentators.

Comment: Thanks Prof Tu!