# Are open subsets of immersed submanifolds immersed submanifolds?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-topology, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold ([with dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if) $m$, if relevant). Let $B$ be an immersed submanifold of $M$. Let $A$ be an open subset of $B$. Is $A$ an immersed submanifold of $M$? I think so. Please verify:

1. By definition of $B$ as an immersed submanifold of $M$, there exists a smooth manifold $N$ and an immersion $F: N \to M$ such that $F(N)=B$.
2. Hopefully, $N$ [has a dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if) $n$ too, if relevant. (I understand that for manifolds with dimension, immersions imply $\dim N \le \dim M$. I don't know of any definition of immersion where $N$ or $M$ may not have dimension.)
3. $A$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$ if there exists a smooth manifold $P$ and an immersion $G: P \to M$ such that $G(P)=A$
4. Choose $P=F^{-1}(A)$ and $G=F|_{F^{-1}(A)}$. This works because:

   - 4.1. $P=F^{-1}(A)$ is a manifold: $F$ is smooth implies $F$ is continuous implies $\tilde F: N \to F(N)=B$ is continuous implies that $P=F^{-1}(A)$ is open in $N$ and thus is a regular/embedded submanifold (of codimension zero) and thus a manifold.
   - 4.2. The image of $G$ is $A$: $G(F^{-1}(A))=F(F^{-1}(A))=A$ since $A \subseteq B = F(N))$.
   - 4.3. $G$ is smooth: This follows by (4.1) because restrictions of smooth maps to (regular/embedded) submanifolds with dimension (The only definition of submanifold I know is where both the submanifold and original manifold have dimensions), including and especially the ones of codimension zero, are smooth.
   - 4.4. $G$ is an immersion: Let $p \in P$. Let $\iota: P \to N$ be the inclusion map, which is proven smooth as part of proving (4.3). Then, by chain rule, $G_{*,p}=(F \circ \iota)_{*,p}=F_{*,p} \circ \iota_{*,p}$. Since inclusions from (regular/embedded) submanifolds are immersions, $G$ is an immersion since compositions of injections are injective.

Comment: That’s a somewhat lengthy way to put it, but it seems correct. Note that the whole discussion on dimension is pointless here, ie only 1,3,4 are relevant. Note also that when doing differential geometry, 4.1 and 4.2 can be asserted without a proof (being rather straightforward set theory and topology).

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks!

Comment: To 2. : A smooth map is a immersion iff at each point the differential is injective. This is the definition given in L. Tu‘s book and does not require the manifolds to have global dimensions.

Comment: @Leo Thanks! Do you agree with Mindlack that dimension is irrelevant here? I can't think of a reason an open subset of a manifold with no uniform dimension such as $\{0\} \cup (1,2)$ wouldn't be a manifold the way open subsets of manifolds with dimensions would be manifolds.

Comment: @Leo Wait are you referring more to (4.4) than to (4.1)?