# Are immersed submanifolds something like local manifolds the same way manifolds are locally Euclidean?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-topology, submanifold

For a (smooth) manifold $M$, the locally Euclidean property goes:

> We have that for each $p \in M$, there exists a positive integer $n_p$ such that there exists a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $U_p$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R^{n_p}$ (If $M$ has a dimension $n$, since [in some textbooks, not all manifolds have uniform dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if), then $n=n_p = n_q$ for all $p, q \in M$).

If we view $U_p$ and $V$ as regular/embedded submanifolds with codimension 0 (of their respective spaces $M$ and $\mathbb R^{n_p}$), then I think we have an analogous local-manifold property for an immersed submanifold $P$:

> Let $M$ be a manifold such that $P$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$. For each $p \in P$, there exists a subset $W_p$ of $P$ that contains $p$ such that $W_p$ is a regular/an embedded submanifold of $M$ ([I'm not too sure about the with or without dimension here for $M$ or $W_p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if)).

- **Edit**: I changed $W_p$ from open to arbitrary subset and then to submanifold (of $M$) and removed ideas of ["diffeomorphism" for arbitrary subsets of manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Diffeomorphisms_of_subsets_of_manifolds).

**Question 0: Is this property correct?**

**Question 1**: Assuming the property is correct, is this proof correct? Assuming the property is incorrect, then what's the error in this proof?

1. By definition of $P$ being an immersed submanifold, there exists manifolds $N$ and $M$ and a smooth map $F: N \to M$ such that $F$ is an immersion with image $F(N)=P$. (I'm not sure if $N$ and $M$ necessarily have [dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if).)
2. Let $p \in P = F(N)$. Then there exists $q \in N$ such that $F(q)=p$.
3. For $q$ in (2), with immersions as equivalent to local embeddings, there exists, by (1), a neighborhood $S_q$ of $q$ in $N$ such that $F|_{S_q}: S_q \to M$ is an embedding.
4. The image of $F|_{S_q}$, $F|_{S_q}(S_q)=F(S_q)$, is a regular/an embedded submanifold of $M$, by (3).
5. Choose $W_p = F(S_q)$, by (4).

- **Edit**: I removed Question 2 asking for a property where $W_p$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$ because $W_p$ is an immersed submanifold since $W_p$ is a regular/an embedded submanifold of $M$.

Comment: Every immersion $F:N \to M$ (whether it is injective or not) is locally on the domain isomorphic to a slice: for each $n \in N$ there are charts around $n$ and $F(n)$ with the property that the map $F$ is, in these charts, equal to the map $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_n,0,\dots,0)$. See e.g. chapter 1 of Warner's excellent book "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups."

Comment: @Stephen What? I know immersions are equivalent to local embeddings. My questions are about immersed submanifolds and not (directly) about immersions themselves.

Comment: Well, the point is that such a slice is diffeomorphic as a subset to Euclidean space (and in fact, something stronger is true: the *pair* $(M,F(N))$ is locally isomorphic to the pair $(\mathbf{R}^m,\mathbf{R}^n)$). I doubt you will find a cleaner proof. (In particular, $S_q$ in your post above can always be chosen in such a way that $F(S_q)$ is open in $F(N)$.)

Comment: @Stephen Ugh...thanks I think...(Trying to understand) Do you mean your answer to the title (i'll make this into "question 0" in an edit now) is "yes", your answer to question 1 is "N/A. Here's what might be the cleanest proof", and your answer to question 2 is "I can find a property stronger than the one in title namely 'the pair...to the pair...' " ?

Comment: I think that's right, if I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen (even if I haven't understood your comment yet)! You can answer if you want

Comment: @Stephen FYI I edited to a better question but hopefully not a vastly different question. You can still answer, I believe.